# How to save the filename of youtube video downloaded from youtube-dl in a variable

Tags: android, youtube-dl

I am making an android app which extracts audio from youtube using youtube-dll. I want to save the title of that youtube video in a variable but command request.option("--get-title") is not returning anything and I don't know how to save it in a variable. Can someone please help. This is the code

```
    YoutubeDLRequest request = new YoutubeDLRequest(url);
    File youtubeDLDir = getDownloadLocation();
    request.setOption("-o", youtubeDLDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/%(title)s.% 
    (ext)s");
    request.setOption("-x");
    request.setOption("--prefer-ffmpeg");
    request.setOption("--add-metadata");
    request.setOption("--metadata-from-title", "%(artist)s - %(title)s");
    request.setOption("--embed-thumbnail");
    request.setOption("--audio-format", "mp3");
```

Comment: As of today, September 11, 2019, `youtube-dl 2019.09.01` is not working with youtube.

Comment: @Deanie Just execute `youtube-dl -U`!

Comment: @csabinho `Just execute youtube-dl -U!` That won't make `youtube-dl 2019.09.01` work.

Comment: @Deanie But why would you want to use an old version?

Comment: @csabinho I didn't say I wanted to use an older version.  I was pointing out that what you said was incorrect.

Comment: @Deanie But why is it relevant if it works with an outdated version? YouTube is changing constantly and that's why you should use the current version. I don't see any point in your comment.

Comment: @Deanie Did you maybe mix up the questions?

Comment: `-U` updates the program. The latest version as of this writing is already `2019.09.12.1`. As youtube updates their application, youtube-dl also does after a while, that's why you should update it to the latest one, to be able to make it work.

Comment: Mine's currently using version `2019.09.12.1`. I downloaded a video to verify if the version is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the static `YoutubeDL.getVideoInfo(String url)`-method. Afterwards you can either save it into a `VideoInfo`-instance or use the member variable directly from the return value.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will give you Title and Extension of Video

```
String[] getVideoInfo(String url) throws YoutubeDLException, InterruptedException {
    VideoInfo streamInfo = YoutubeDL.getInstance().getInfo(url);
    return new String[]{streamInfo.getTitle(), streamInfo.getExt()};
}
```

then access it like this

```
 String title = getVideoInfo(url)[0];
 String extension = getVideoInfo(url)[1];
```